# How to calculate the time difference between two days in seconds

Tags: php

i have a php page .

Here i will get the start time as query string (eg **$startTime= '8/27/2010 1:15:17 PM'**)

Now i need to find out  the **total seconds** between the current time and started time

How can i find out this in php

Answer (score 1):

`echo`[`time()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.time.php)`-`[`strtotime($startTime)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)`;`