# Getting time in seconds

Tags: php

```
<?php 

    $target = mktime(0, 0, 0, 10, 25, 2010) ;
    $today = time () ;
    $difference =($target-$today) ;
    echo $output = $difference/60 ;

?>
```

will the above code give time in seconds

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to calculate the time difference between two days in seconds](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3587952/how-to-calculate-the-time-difference-between-two-days-in-seconds)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No it will give in minutes :) remove the "/60";